# How to copy and paste a table' s column or row?

Tags: gtk, glade

I have a table which repeat each column *x* times.  I could copy and past each row element *x* times but that is tedious.  Is there a way to copy and past the whole column (or row) in glade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: close Glade, open the XML file in your favorite editor, and copy/paste there.

Comment: Yup, that's what I am doing.  *sigh* That's rather painful.